# ("Grand Total: $%.2f" (grand_total)) in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting a Syntax Error: Invalid syntax for the following print statement:

```
print("Grand Total: $%.2f" (grand_total))
```

Can anyone help?

I have tried different variations with no luck.

```
# Set dictionary and lists
grocery_item = {}
grocery_history = []
stop = 'go'
# Shopping list loop
while stop != 'q':
    item_name = input("Item name:\n")
    quantity = input("Quantity purchased:\n")
    cost = input("Price per item:\n")
    grocery_item['name'] = item_name
    grocery_item ['number'] = int(quantity)
    grocery_item['price'] = float(cost)
    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)
    stop = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")

grand_total = 0
# Total items/ cost
for grocery_item in grocery_history:
    item_total = grocery_item['number'] * grocery_item['price']
    # Compute grand total
    grand_total = item_total + grand_total
    # Print Gracery History List
    print(grocery_item[number] + grocery_item['name'] + " @ $%.2f" + grocery_item['price'] + " ea $%.2f" + (item_total)
    # Print Grang Total
    print("Grand Total: $%.2f" (grand_total))
```

```
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
Item name:
Quantity purchased:
Price per item:
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
1 milk @ $2.99 ea $2.99
2 eggs @ $3.99 ea $7.98
4 onions @ $0.79 ea $3.16
Grand total: $14.13
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate What's much more likely missed is a string formatting operator `%` rather than a comma.

Comment: The prolem is what @blhsing said. You forgot the `%` operator after the string. It should be like `print("Grand Total: $%.2f" % (grand_total))`

Comment: I tried both, neither worked.

Comment: This is in Codio Project 2 Grocery List

Comment: @blhsing Oops, you're right. The lack of comma causes a TypeError, not a SystaxError.

Answer (score 0):

Besides missing the string formatting operator `%` in the last call to `print`, as already pointed out in the comments, you are also missing a closing right parenthesis in the second last call to `print`:

```
print(grocery_item[number], grocery_item['name'] % " @ $%.2f", grocery_item['price'], " ea $%.2f" % (item_total))
```